# What does `filter2` do in this code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

```
function G=costfunction(im) 
   G=zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
   for ii=1:size(im,3) 
      G=G+(filter2([.5 1 .5; 1 -6 1; .5 1 .5],im(:,:,ii))).^2; 
   end
end
```

Here, `im` is an input image (rgb image).
What will this cost function return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit:

```
filter2([.5 1 .5; 1 -6 1; .5 1 .5],im(:,:,ii))
```

applies a [Laplace filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator) to one 2D slice of `im`. Usually, the Laplace filter is implemented as `[0 1 0; 1 -4 1; 0 1 0]` or `[1 1 1; 1 -8 1; 1 1 1]`. I guess whoever wrote this code couldn't decide between those two and took the average.

The loop runs through each of the 2D slices in the 3D image `im`, and adds the square of each of the results together. If `im` is an RGB image, it will apply the filter to each of the color channels, and add the square of the results.

The Laplace operator gives a strong negative response on thin lines in the image, as well as responses (positive and negative) around the edges in an image. By taking the square, all responses are positive. Note that the cost function will be close to zero on edges, but high just inside and outside the edges.

Comment: * I guess whoever wrote this code couldn't decide between those two and took the average.* ? Do you have any insight of why would anyone do this? I mean, is there any scientific reason to actually do it?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: the 3x3 Laplace filters are finite difference approximations to the actual Laplace, which you can't compute on a discrete grid. They are poor choices to begin with because they are noise sensitive. Nonetheless, they have their uses. The -4 version is the "correct" one, as the sum of the second derivative along each axis. The -8 one adds the corners leading to less noise sensitivity. This -6 one here looks like it is a more rotationally invariant option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `filter2` is the same used for **image processing**(as tagged in the question) it should do a 2d linear filtering, `im` will get its data filtered in the matrix `[.5 1 .5; 1 -6 1; .5 1 .5]` with the 2d FIR filter.
For the return, `G` should be that `zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2))` plus all the processed images there.

Comment: Thank you, But can you be more elaborate on what actually this [.5 1 .5; 1 -6 1; .5 1 .5] means ?

Comment: I don't about how that matrix will affect the image, each `;` is supposed to create a row, I recommend you checking these links: [Matrices and Digital Images](http://blog.kleinproject.org/?p=588), [Matrix Filter Representations](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Matrix_Filter_Representations.html) and [MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) where you can even run codes.

That's a matrix with `.5 1 .5` in the first row, `1 -6 1` in the second, etc

Comment: It looks like a modification of the 2D Laplacian - an edge detector.  See here: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm.  BTW please use `imfilter` if you can.  `filter2` is not designed for images.